# regarding tcp endpoints in wcf

Tags: wcf

now see tcp endpoint

```
<endpoint address="tcp"
                      binding="netTcpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
                      contract="ChatService.IChat"/>
```

tcp endpoint address has no url rather tcp the word has been assign to address property...why?

give me a sample url which can be a valid tcp url.

the address field of tcp endpoint will always have the fixed word called "tcp" is it rule or convention.

### here is full binding sample

```
<service name="WCFService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="behaviorConfig">

<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/"/>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1648/ChatServer/"/>
  </baseAddresses>
  </host>
  <endpoint address="tcp"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
                  contract="ChatService.IChat"/>

 <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/mex"
                  binding="mexTcpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

 </service>
```

Comment: The **full** address for your endpoint will be `net.tcp://localhost:1465/ChatServer/tcp` (the first part from the **base address** for the `net.tcp` scheme, the rest from your actual endpoint definition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having the full configuration file, I cannot tell you the exact thing, but my guesses are:

I. **address="tcp"**

a. There is a setting for the host base address, so the full address will be base address + tcp. For example the following service has the base address

> ```
>  ...
>       <host>
>          <baseAddresses>
>          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://MyServerIPAddress:9000/MyService.svc" />
>        </baseAddresses>
>      </host>
>      ...
> ```

b. Or  the actual address of the endpoint will be set at the run time for the service contract.

II. A sample valid tcp **uri**

> ```
>  <endpoint address="net.tcp://MyServerIPAddress:9000/tcp"
>                        binding="netTcpBinding"
>                        bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
>                        contract="ChatService.IChat"/>
> ```

III. For the tcp binding the address must start with **net.tcp**, and it's a rule.

For more information you can have a look at the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734786.aspx)

Comment: i gave my full binding sample....please have a look and tell me what address people use to create proxy. if i omit base address in my config above given then proxy creation will be possible?

Comment: Hello there the address that  people use to created the proxy is net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/tcp

Comment: thanks but i can give also mex address like net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/mex to create proxy. so tell me what will be the difference to create proxy using two different url. another one important question is that why two url has been expose to create proxy...is there any special reason. please guide...thanks

Comment: Hello there, if you don't specify the whole address which is start by scheme://address then the default base address will be used. There isn't any difference in creating proxies. There are two different base addresses because one is used for tcp protocol(baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/") and the other for http protocol (<add baseAddress="http://localhost:1648/ChatServer/"/>)